# Does color order really matter?

Tags: ethernet

Im not comprehending this probably basic concept. If the wires in a ethernet jack are one color coded way on one end of the cable  and in the same order on the other, why am I having issues? When I run them as 568b or 568a, everything works fine.

But when I run them as:

```
brown/stripe brown------brown/stripe brown
Blue/stripe blue------Blue/stripe blue
Green/stripe green------Green/stripe green
Orange/stripe orange------Orange/stripe orange
```

I have communication issues. Why? The device doesn't know the colors are in a different order, nor are they different on the other end. I am not comprehending why there is an issue with my way, and when I do it the 568 way its fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet uses differential signaling on twisted pairs. If you switch out a single wire in two pairs, their magnetic fields won't cancel out as intended.

The isolation around the copper will stop voltage, but not magnetic fields. Over long cable runs this causes [crosstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstalk), where the signal of one wire leaks to a nearby one via inductive coupling. In the early days of telephony, this effect could lead to hearing other peoples phone calls in your own line.

In ethernet over copper this is mitigated by running two wires (pair) twisted together where the wires voltages are negated. So if one wire has a potential of +1V, its counterpart has a voltage of -1V. This results in practically no magnetic field surrounding the pairs.

> 1000BASE-T uses all four pairs bi-directionally using hybrid circuits and cancellers. Data is encoded using 4D-PAM5; four dimensions using pulse-amplitude modulation (PAM) with five voltages, −2 V, −1 V, 0 V, +1 V, and +2 V. While +2 V to −2 V may appear at the pins of the line driver, the voltage on the cable is nominally +1 V, +0.5 V, 0 V, −0.5 V and −1 V.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair#Cabling)

So if you switch individual wires between the pairs, you effectively pry out these mitigation measures. Due to the fast switching on the wires and the relatively low voltages, a signal then cannot be decoded at the receiving end.

You see, fast data transfer is only possible through careful juggling with physical properties, it can be enough to disturb one facet to bring the entire system to a fall.